# Basic auth AND oAuth with cemerick/friend in Clojure

Tags: authentication, clojure

I have basic auth up and running and want to include oAuth through facebook and twitter to my web app.

If I interpret the friend's github correctly, I need separate workflow for every authentication method. Friend will try each of them with the parameters it called with until it successfully authenticates or no workflows remain, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cf. also [Adam Bard's friend introduction](http://adambard.com/blog/easy-auth-with-friend/) which has a brief explanation of this.